# Jquery POST request to another PHP file not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a post request to send some data from one php file to another. I'm using Jquery and my code looks as follows

**My post file:**

```
$(function (){
    $(".commit").click(function(){
        const sha_id = $(this).data("sha");
        $.ajax({
            url : 'commitInfo.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : sha_id,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(response){
                console.log(sha_id);
                window.location.replace("commitInfo");
            }
        });    
    });
});
```

**My receiving file:**

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

The `$_POST` returns an empty array. And have also tried placing my data inside of an object. Doesn't work either. Anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: I thing you are not getting value in `sha_id`. Try to alert `sha_id` value in your ajax. Or check in console what value you are passing.

Comment: Tried alert(sha_id) and it appears.

Comment: you have mentioned `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` so you should pass value in JSON format like `data :{ sha_id:sha_id},` try this one.

Comment: I tried that as well, no go :(

Comment: @NitinKawane That's _not_ [JSON](http://json.org) and will and as "sha_id=<value of sha_id>" in the body of the request

Comment: Can you add `HTML` for `button` you're clicking on it to run this `AJAX` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your variable which contain data before sending the ajax request to the server by console it to the browser.
Ajax request carry data into key value pair or json format you need to send json object to the server to get the access to the data

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'whatever-folder/whatever-url.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : { anykey: anything },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response){
         console.log(response);
    }
});
```

and you will get the post in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried using the `FormData` [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

```
$(function (){
    $(".commit").click(function(){
        const sha_id = $(this).data("sha");
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('id',sha_id );
        $.ajax({
            url : 'commitInfo.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response){
                 console.log(sha_id);
                 window.location.replace("commitInfo");
            }
        });
     });
 });
```

Comment: [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) -> _"type (default: 'GET'), Type: String, **An alias for `method`**. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0."_

Answer (score 0):

```
(1.). post file:

$(function (){
    $(".commit").click(function(){
        const sha_id = $(this).data("sha");
        $.ajax({
            url : 'commitInfo.php',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : sha_id,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(response){
                console.log(sha_id);
                window.location.replace("commitInfo");
            }
        });    
    });
});




(2.). Json data does not receive in post.

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($post);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Hello, when I try this, it fails. The success condition never occurs.